# Django filter a queryset with field value lookup

Tags: python, django

I have a model that has 2 decimal fields

```
class Order (models.Model):    
    ordered = models.DecimalField(...)
    received = models.DecimalField(...)
```

I need to retrieve the rows where `received` is less than `ordered`.

Something like:

```
SELECT * from Order WHERE received < ordered
```

Is there a django syntax way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> Order.objects.filter(received__lt=F('ordered'))
```